# Plotting a boxplot without using 'toPandas' and in a one graph

Tags: pyspark, boxplot

I want to plot 'boxplot' of two different columns od a dataframe. I use the following code in pyspark python3:

```
c1 = df.where(F.col('c1') > 0.0).select(F.col('c1')).toPandas()
c2 = df.where(F.col('c1') > 0.0).select(F.col('c2')).toPandas()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
c1.boxplot(ax = ax1)
c2.boxplot(ax = ax2)
```

Is there any way to plot them

1. without using '.toPandas'?
2. in one picture like the following figure?

[image]

Comment: Was it resolved? I'm trying to do the same thing as well but with no luck.